# Interpret Java to PHP or Laravel

Tags: java, php, laravel

I have a project convertng JAVA to PHP/Laravel and stumble on this problem. Anyone could interpret for me from JAVA to PHP or Laravel and what the code does. I know it sorts "something" but I don't know all what the code in the Controller does. All help are greatly appreciated. Thank You.

```
// Payment Model
public String getLimitDate() {
    return limitDate; // private String limitDate;
}

// Controller
List<Payment> payment = paymentService.methodChanged(userIdx, 6, "7,8");
List<Payment> paymentList15 = new ArrayList<>();

Collections.sort(paymentList15, new Comparator<Payment>() {
    public int compare(Payment obj1, Payment obj2) {
        return obj2.getLimitDate().compareToIgnoreCase(obj1.getLimitDate());
    }
});
```

Comment: You want to convert this java syntaxe to PHP ?

Comment: Post your complete code

Comment: If using laravel you can start with creating the Payment class in php and using a Laravel collection to hold an array of them inside. Sorting is also something you can do with that collection class.

Answer (score 1):

`limitDate` is some String representation of the date
and method `compare` compares those dates alphabetically
so you sort paymentList by `limitDate` alphabetically

Comment: Thank you for enlightenment.